# Android: how to get value of an attribute in code?

Tags: android

I would like to retrieve the int value of textApperanceLarge in code.  I believe that the below code is going in the right direction, but can't figure out how to extract the int value from the TypedValue.

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
((Activity)context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge, typedValue, true);
```

Comment: Similar to [Accessing attrs in AttributeSet for custom components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302229/accessing-attrs-in-attributeset-for-custom-components)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Your code only gets the resource ID of the style that the *textAppearanceLarge* attribute points to, namely *TextAppearance.Large* as Reno points out.

To get the *textSize* attribute value from the style, just add this code:

```
int[] textSizeAttr = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize };
int indexOfAttrTextSize = 0;
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, textSizeAttr);
int textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(indexOfAttrTextSize, -1);
a.recycle();
```

Now *textSize* will be the text size in pixels of the style that *textApperanceLarge* points to, or -1 if it wasn't set. This is assuming *typedValue.type* was of type TYPE_REFERENCE to begin with, so you should check that first.

The number *16973890* comes from the fact that it is the resource ID of [*TextAppearance.Large*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#TextAppearance_Large)

Comment: works like a charm. just why does it have to be so complicated... is there no less obscure approach by now, six years later?

Comment: What's typedValue? Is a class name, a typeof, a variable...? typedValue as class has not a .data field

Answer (score 64):

Using

```
  TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
  ((Activity)context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge, typedValue, true);
```

For the string :

```
typedValue.string
typedValue.coerceToString()
```

For other data :

```
typedValue.resourceId
typedValue.data  // (int) based on the type
```

In your case what it returns is of the `TYPE_REFERENCE`.

I know it should point to [TextAppearance.Large](http://www.google.co.in/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/styles.xml&exact_package=android&q=TextAppearance.Large&type=cs)

Which is :

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Credit goes to Martin for resolving this :

```
int[] attribute = new int[] { android.R.attr.textSize };
TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.resourceId, attribute);
int textSize = array.getDimensionPixelSize(0, -1);
```

Comment: typedValue.data evaluates to: 16973890.  This doesn't seem correct, for a text size.

Comment: @ab11 it is not the text size. It is the integer of the dimensions resource.

Answer (score 16):

Or in kotlin:

```
fun Context.dimensionFromAttribute(attribute: Int): Int {
    val attributes = obtainStyledAttributes(intArrayOf(attribute))
    val dimension = attributes.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0)
    attributes.recycle()
    return dimension
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an inquisition on the @user3121370's answer. They burned down. :O

If you just need the get a dimension, like a padding, minHeight (my case was: android.R.attr.listPreferredItemPaddingStart). You can do:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue(); 
((Activity)context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemPaddingStart, typedValue, true);
```

Just like the question did, and then:

```
final DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int myPaddingStart = typedValue.getDimension( metrics );
```

Just like the removed answer. This will allow you to skip handling device pixel sizes, because it uses the default device metric. The return will be float, and you should cast to int.

Becareful to the type you are trying to get, like resourceId.

Answer (score 1):

this is my code.

```
public static int getAttributeSize(int themeId,int attrId, int attrNameId)
{
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Context ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(getBaseContext(), themeId);

    ctx.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attrId, typedValue, true);

    int[] attributes = new int[] {attrNameId};
    int index = 0;
    TypedArray array = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, attributes);
    int res = array.getDimensionPixelSize(index, 0);
    array.recycle();
    return res;
} 

// getAttributeSize(theme, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge, android.R.attr.textSize)   ==>  return android:textSize
```