# Android get current text appearance

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, textview, android-developer-api

How to retrieve current text appearance of a text view. I know there are some methods like `getCurrentTextColor()` that would give me current text color. I want to get current text appearance. I want to use this text appearance at a later point.

Is there any way for it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: a text appearance simply sets multiple properties and once they are set you can't afaik get the appearance that did this.There can also be multiple styles and appearances that work together so the end result might even be a combination. https://sebhastian.com/android-textappearance/ has a few details

Comment: if you use your own custom TextView subclass you can apparently get the textappearance out of the `AttributeSet` that is set by the layout inflater and would be used to apply the actual properties of the textview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983629/android-get-textappearance-runtime

Comment: Pls go through this site. https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.widget.TextView/getTextColors