# Retrieve margins from attributes

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the margins from the `.xml` file. Currently I'm doing it like so:

```
mUserDefinedLeftMargin = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_marginLeft", 0);
```

where `attrs` is of type `AttributeSet` (it's received in the constructor or my class which extends `RelativeLayout`)

The `.xml` looks like this:

```
    <ch......MyCustomView
        android:id="@+id/update_progress"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

`mUserDefinedLeftMargin` is still 0 at the end of the above call. Why ?

Comment: It is because dp is not int value. Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302229/accessing-attrs-in-attributeset-for-custom-components. It is string and you should convert it it to points yourself

Comment: excellent ! Please write it as an response, so I can accept it

Comment: don't do that,  use Context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs) instead, no need for converting a String like "14.0sp" to float value

Comment: @pskink can you write an answer?

Comment: @EugenMartynov just use TypedArray.getDimension*() to get the float value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because **dp** is not int value. You should first get it as text:

```
String dpSizeText = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "layout_marginLeft");
```

And convert it to pixels after:

```
int dpSizeInt = Integer.parseInt(dpSizeText.substring(0, dpSizeText.indexOf("dp")));
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpSizeInt, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: @AndreiBogdan please don't do that, use Context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs) instead