# How to read android default attributes of a View in java code

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to have a custom TextView called MyTextView and i want to set a default TextSize in it's constructor only if no TextSize has been set in it's XML definition. How can i detect if a TextSize has been set in it's XML definition?

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{    
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        //How can i read TextSize from AttribureSet??
        //if no TextSize has been set then SetTextSize(defaultTextSize);
    } 
}
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: This Question (and Answer) should be just the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302229/accessing-attrs-in-attributeset-for-custom-components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain style attributes like

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView{    
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
         String size = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "textSize");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this returns exactly the string which has been set in xml definition like "12.0sp" or null or something like this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's example:

```
final Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
TypedArray array = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.YourStylable, R.attr.YourDefStyleAttr, 0);
```

Comment: this only works if custom attributes are set. not the default.

Comment: Thank you, but i want to now about default attributes and not custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `float size = new TextView(this).getTextSize();`

Comment: I think this returns the textSize and cannot recognize it is the default textSize or it has been set in the xml layout file.