# custom style - retrieve color attr in code - working well as long the color is not #ffffffff

Tags: android, styles, attr

I have defined a color attr, set it in a style and I am using the below code to use the value. Everything is working fine as long the color is different from #ffffffff (means according to the code below, for any color defined in the style the color variable is getting the correct value, but for white the value in color is -1). 
It seems that with my code the color value must be smaller than #ffffffff and I don't understand why.

this is the attr definition:
`<attr name="viewLvActive" format="color"/>`

this is the line in the custom style:
`<item name="@attr/viewLvActive">#ffffffff</item>`

This is the code, which I use to get this color value from my theme:

```
Resources.Theme theme = mCtx.getTheme();
TypedValue styleID = new TypedValue();
if (theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.viewLvActive, styleID, true))
    color=styleID.data;
else
    color=-1;
```

Finally I can live with a color of #fffffffe but still I would like to know where is the mistake.

Comment: see this [get value of an attribute in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896615/android-how-to-get-value-of-an-attribute-in-code)

Comment: That's clear so far and actually my code is according to this answer

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the `color` variable? Because if it's `int`, then `-1 == #ffffffff`. If you're checking something like:

```
if (color == -1) {
```

you'll get `true` for #ffffffff. An `int` is 32 bits and an ARGB color will fill all of it up. You can't use a value like -1 (or any other value) to mean "no color".