# Getting the same value for textStyle attribut in styles.xml

Tags: android

I'm trying to extract the value set on this attribut `<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>`

According to the documentation the return values for this attribut are

**Normal: 0**

**Bold: 1**

**Italic: 2**

But I'm always getting 0 for `styleVal`  no matter what is passed in the textStyle! 
Everything in the code seems correcet and I can't debug the error

```
    private void getTextViewStyleValue() {

            int[] AttrSet = {
            android.R.attr.textColor,
            android.R.attr.textStyle,
            android.R.attr.fontFamily,
    };

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(style, AttrSet);

    textColor = a.getColor(0, DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);

    int styleVal = a.getInt(1, 0);

    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), a.getString(2));

    a.recycle();

}
```

This is what is written about `android.R.attr.textStyle`'s value

[image]

Comment: Try a.getInteger since is an enum.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896615/ddg#7913610

Comment: @Mihai doesn't make any differnece, see my updated post

Comment: You sould not declare again the attributes declared by the system , if you need to use one you need to do it this way `<attr name="android:textStyle"/>`