# How can I set attr value in ImageView from class?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, attr

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar_repo_list"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="?attr/avatar_repo_icon"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

like this, but from the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get the reference of your image-view in your Activity class through "ID", and then add attr value like this:

[Android: how to get value of an attribute in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896615/android-how-to-get-value-of-an-attribute-in-code)

Answer (score 0):

In you `activity`, Get the reference of this `image view` using `findViewById()` and then you can use this reference to call the methods. These methods then set the attribute value of your `image view`. Here is the exemplary snippet.

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar_repo_list);
//Suppose I need to set the Drawable programatically    
img.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
```