# Resolving the value of "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" in code

Tags: android, android-custom-view

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896615/android-how-to-get-value-of-an-attribute-in-code) helped a bit, but doesn't quite cover my issue.

Here is what my XML looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ... other attributes...
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    >
```

The issue is that I would like to be able to resolve that attr in code. Here is what I have so far:

```
val typedValue = TypedValue()
context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, typedValue, true)
typedValue.string // "res/drawable/item_background_material.xml"
typedValue.type   // 3 (string)
typedValue.data   // 656
```

I could use the linked answer, I suppose, to directly resolve `R.drawable.item_background_material`, but the whole point of using `?android:attr/...` is that I don't *know* where that attr points. How do I make use of the information contained in the `TypedValue` object to resolve the drawable reference?

Btw, I have tried

```
val drawableRes = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, string.indexOf(".xml")) // gross, but it's just a proof of concept
val drawable = resources.getIdentifier(drawableRes, "drawable", context.packageName)
```

but the result is always `0`.

Comment: Look at the [`resourceId` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#resourceId). That is, `typedValue.resourceId`.

Comment: a-ha! that totally worked. `val drawable = context.getDrawable(typedValue.resourceId)`. If you submit that as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That resource identifier will be in the [`resourceId` field](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#resourceId). That is, in your example, `typedValue.resourceId`.

For anyone using Kotlin, here's a pretty neat way to implement that:

```
foreground = with(TypedValue()) {
    context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, this, true)
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
}
```