# Obtain android attr in custom view

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, view

I have a custom view which extends RelativeLayout. I have some custom attrs in `attrs.xml`. Is there a way to obtain common android attrs like `android:clickable` like we do with custom attributes?

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?): RelativeLayout(context, attributeSet) {
  init {
      val attrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.MyView)
    
      if (attrs.getBoolean(android.R.attr.clickable, true)) {
          ...
      }
    
      attrs.recycle()
  }
```

}

This compiler accepts, but it crashed on runtime. Anyone have come across similar use case? I would like to avoid creating duplicate attrs for custom view which are already defined in SDK.

Comment: By extending `RelativeLayout` the custom view inherits its attributes. You usually don't need to "touch" them unless your intention is to change the parent's behaviour which, actually, might be confusing/unpredictable for a user/developer.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913610/5909412

Comment: Why is crashing? What is the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

More or less, the answer was in front of me the whole time. One thing that I had to understand, that when you create a stylable its basically an `IntArray`. Now when you obtain attributes and pass yout stylable reference, it maps attributes bassed on its definition.
So in order to obtain other attributes, which are not declared in your local attrs, like those `android:` which are in the SDK, you need to pass those references in as an `IntArray`:

```
class MyView(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet?): RelativeLayout(context, attributeSet) {
    init {
        val attrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, intArrayOf(android.R.attr.clickable))

        if (attrs.getBoolean(0, true)) {
            ...
        }

        attrs.recycle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, probably this one should work

at `attrs.xml` you should declare smth like that

```
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
        <attr name="android:clickable" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

And at your `MyCustomView` class you should obtain desired properties from typed array like:

```
val clickable = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyCustomView_android_clickable, false)
```

Comment: I know this. I want to avoid this if there is already a an attribute of this kind in SDK.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Because I don't want to have duplicate attribute names. This could confuse in future why having `android:clickable` and `app:clickable` if both represent the same exact expected behaviour.

Comment: this one method will allow you to intercept `android:clickable` as you declare `<attr name="android:clickable" />`. Please, read it carefully

Comment: You should only to declare `android:clickable` at your view

Comment: @parohy, do you have a chance to try it?